# Function to Show a div on mousehover or hide div on mouseout into forEach with Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I'd like to make a function to show the `div id="capa-video"` on mouseover and play the video and hide the `<div id="capa-imagem">` on mouseout and pause the video. You can see the code below

```
<div class="thumbnailBig"> 
  <a href="#" title="text" class="link">
    <div id="capa-imagem"> 
        <img src="<?php echo $thumbnail_src[0]; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />      
    </div>
    
    <div id="capa-video">
        <video preload="none" muted id="video-tocar"> 
            <source src="<?= $mostrar_preview ?>" type="video/mp4">                 
        </video>
    </div> 
</a> </div>
```

That code below is a forEach function in php

```
<?php echo $thumbnail_src[0]; ?>
<?= $mostrar_preview ?>
```

And my javacript code is

```
var mostrar = document.getElementsByTagName("thumbnailBig");
[].forEach.call(mostrar, function(item){
item.addEventListener('mouseover', hoverMostrar, false);
item.addEventListener('mouseout', hideMostrar, false);
});

function hoverMostrar(e){
document.getElementById("capa-video").style.display = "block";
document.getElementById("capa-imagem").style.display = "none";  
}

function hideMostrar(e){
document.getElementById("capa-video").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("capa-imagem").style.display = "block";  
}

var vid = document.getElementsByTagName("video");  
[].forEach.call(vid, function(item){
item.addEventListener('mouseover', hoverVideo, false);
item.addEventListener('mouseout', hideVideo, false);    
});

function hoverVideo(e){
 this.play();    
}

function hideVideo(e){
  this.pause();    
}
```

My code could play the video on mouseover and pause the video on mouseout, but I can't toggle between show or hide the `div id="capa-imagem"` to `<div id="capa-video">`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're duplicating ID for elements *capa-imagem* and *capa-video* change that to class, so you won't have issues accessing them.

Another error is that you're trying to get containers with `document.getElementsByTagName("thumbnailBig");`, but that's the container class name. Use [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) instead.

Then, loop items using `NodeList.forEach()` to add event listeners. I've commented every block of code, so you can know how it works. Feel free to ask if you have any doubt.

```js
// Get all containers by its class name
let thumbs = document.querySelectorAll('.thumbnailBig');
// Get all videos by its tag name
let videos = document.querySelectorAll('video');

// Add event listeners for containers
thumbs.forEach(thumb => {
    thumb.addEventListener('mouseover', hoverMostrar);
    thumb.addEventListener('mouseout', hideMostrar);
});

function hoverMostrar(e) {
    // e is the fired event, "this" is not available here, it refers to window
    // e.target is the element that fires the event
    // closest() will find parent, if not, will return same element
    let thumb = e.target.closest('.thumbnailBig');
    // From parent, search for image and video containers to show or hide
    thumb.querySelector('.capa-imagem').style.display = 'none';
    thumb.querySelector('.capa-video').style.display = 'block';
}

function hideMostrar(e) {
    let thumb = e.target.closest('.thumbnailBig');
    thumb.querySelector('.capa-imagem').style.display = 'block';
    thumb.querySelector('.capa-video').style.display = 'none';
}

// Add listeners for video
videos.forEach(video => {
    // e.target is the video that fired the event
    video.addEventListener('mouseover', e => e.target.play());
    video.addEventListener('mouseout', e => e.target.pause());
});
```

```css
.thumbnailBig img {
    max-width:100px;
    max-height:100px;
}
.capa-imagen {
    display: block;
}
.capa-video {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="thumbnailBig">
  <a href="#" title="text" class="link">
    <div class="capa-imagem"> 
        <img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png" alt="airplane" />      
    </div>
    <div class="capa-video">
        <video preload="none" muted id="video-tocar"> 
            <source src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">                 
        </video>
    </div> 
  </a>
</div>

<div class="thumbnailBig">
  <a href="#" title="text" class="link">
    <div class="capa-imagem"> 
        <img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png" alt="airplane" />      
    </div>
    <div class="capa-video">
        <video preload="none" muted id="video-tocar"> 
            <source src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">                 
        </video>
    </div> 
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: It works like a charm. I've been coding all day long and I don't see these errors that you show me. Tks a lot. Put querySelectorAll its so much easy.

Answer (score 0):

Simple fix. Instead of passing your event listener a named callback, pass an anonymous callback declaration and invoke your two handlers.

```
item.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
    hoverVideo();
    hoverMostar();
});
```

Comment: I thought I should put a named callback all the time. Tks

Comment: I'm not sure where you learned that but you can do either, in this case you need to run two functions so you should use something like the example above.